# How can write method act similar to clone method of object?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, access-specifier

I observed clone is method of `Object` Class and `Object` is super class of every class. In every class i'm getting the clone as override method, suppose i create class with name `A` if I'm not override `clone` method at `class A`, and created an object for A I'm not getting the access of clone method in a object

What the concept i'm missing in oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues: first, `clone()` is a `protected` method of `Object`, so it can only be called from within the subclass unless you override it and make it public. Second, unless your class implements `Cloneable`, calling `clone()` will throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`. The typical approach is:

```
class A implements Cloneable {
    public Object clone() {
         try {
             return super.clone();
         } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Impossible exception!", e);
         }
    }
}
```

(You could eliminate the try/catch block and declare your `clone()` method to throw `CloneNotSupportedException`. The method would be simpler but all the calling code would have to deal with the exception.)

Since Java allows you to narrow the return type when overriding a method, you could redefine `clone()` to return an `A`, saving the calling code from having to cast:

```
class A implements Cloneable {
    public A clone() {
         try {
             return (A) super.clone();
         } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Impossible exception!", e);
         }
    }
}
```